# Extjs how to add html div as item

Tags: html, extjs

How can I place a `div` component as children and having access to it using Exjs?

This is what I tried:

```
Ext.define('mycomponent.mywindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    id: 'mywindow',
    xtype: 'mywindow',

    modal: true,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    height: 400,
    width: 575,
    closeAction: 'destroy',
    resizable: false,

    items: [
        {
            html: '<div id="mydiv">Hi there</div>'
        },
        {
           ...
        }
    ],

    initComponent: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

This div will have editable content.

That code displays de div, but, how to style it and how to access its contents? Also, is there any `xtype: div` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in two ways. One is with direct html source string while other is using Ext.Xtemplate. Ext.Xtemplate is considered good since it provides a good control over events, data as well as validations.

Here is simple poc code:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        //Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: "hello",
            items: [
                {
                    html: `<div contenteditable="true">I am raw implementation</div>`,
                    listeners: {
                        input: {
                            fn: function() {
                                console.log("Changed one")
                            },
                            element: "element",
                            selector: "div"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: "container",
                    data: {
                        initialValue:"I am with template<script>alert(2);</script>"
                    },
                    tpl: `<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">{initialValue:htmlEncode}</div>`,
                    listeners: {
                        click: {
                            fn: function() {
                                console.log("clicked")
                            },
                            element: "element",
                            selector: "#editor"
                        },
                        input: {
                            fn: function() {
                                console.log("Changed two");
                            },
                            element: "element",
                            selector: "#editor"
                        }
                    }
                }]
        })
    }
});
```

Here is working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2srn

Since you are trying to build something very near to dom it might run into XSS issues so you see `htmlEncode` in xtemplate. If you want to have certain tags while drop other tags, which I believe is the use case for adopting to contenteditor div,   you take a look at https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?67547-Template-XSS-and-encodeHtml which explains how you can write your own functions that can be used in Ext.XTemplate instances.